# Java multidimensional multi type Array (Map/List/Collection)?

Tags: java, list, multidimensional-array

We have a declaration like this:

`ArrayList<Map<String, Map<Integer, Object>>> parameterSet = new ArrayList<Map<String, Map<Integer, Object>>>();`

Probably it's possible to define it in a way like this (I know, it's wrong, please take it as pseudo code):

`List<List<String, Integer, Object>> parameterSet = new ...;`

I'm pretty sure, there is a better way to define such a two dimensional multi-type "array".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is not the dimension but the "multi-type".

Either you find a common super-type for your elements (last resort can always be `Object`) or you create a wrapper class that can hold whatever type you need.

```
List<Object>
```

Having `Object` objects is fast and "easy" but it can get messy when you need to cast the elements to their actual class. Depending on how many different types you want to hold in you list, the ifs can become quite complex:

```
Object elem = mylist.get(i);
if(elem instanceof Float){
   Float floatElem = (Float) elem;
}
...
```

More precise would be the wrapper class

```
public class Wrapper<T>  {
     private T data;

     // constructors can be nice
     public Wrapper(Float f){this.data=f;}
     public Wrapper(Double d){this.data=d;}
     public Wrapper(String s){this.data=s;}

     public void setData(T newData) {
         data = newData;
     }

     public T getData() {
         return data;
     }

     // you can add convenience methods to find out what type your wrapper holds
     public boolean isString(){
         return this.data instanceof String;  // for example
     }

     // and also convenience methods to "cast" your data 
     public Float asFloat(){
        return (Float) this.data;
     }
}
```

Then your List will only need to hold your wrapper class

```
List<Wrapper> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Wrapper<Float>(1.2f));
```

And to check the type of your element you can use your convenience methods:

```
if(list.get(i).isFloat()){
  Float f = list.get(i).asFloat();
}
```

Comment: Thx, looks good but also "complex". I was hoping there is a one-line solution. Nevertheless it seems we have to go this way.

Comment: You are right, it is far from a one-liner. But at least you can keep the "complex" stuff in a single place.

Answer (score 0):

Using standard Java Collection API, you can do basically 2 things:

1. Use `List` instead of `ArrayList` in the declaration: `List<Map<String, Map<Integer, Object>>> parameterSet = new ArrayList<Map<String, Map<Integer, Object>>>();`
2. Use the diamond operator (if you are using Java 7+): `List<Map<String, Map<Integer, Object>>> parameterSet = new ArrayList<>();`

Still, in this case, I would consider defining a class encapsulating the complex data structure (map of map).

Comment: Hm, this was not really the question .. or didn't I understand your answer in the right way? I'm looking for a solution without the second 'Map'.